# Improve syntax detection based on shebang

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

On a few occasion, I've seen code blocks such as:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

echo foo/*
echo this is not part of a C comment.
```

Being highlighted as C code even though the Q&A had a zsh tag and the shebang made it explicit what language the code is written in.

I feel like it should be relatively easy for the syntax highlighting code to detect this kind of situation and select the `zsh` syntax highlighter automatically here based on the shebang.

In any case, that's not limited to `zsh`, `zsh` just happens to be the language I use in most of my posts here. It would be useful for code blocks starting with `#! /bin/bash -` / `#! /usr/bin/perl --`, etc as well.

Comment: Glorfindel's answer makes me wonder if it's a problem for bash shebang as well.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, my point here was more a feature request about getting the highlighter to consider the shebang. Yes, I've seen the highlighter making the wrong guess for a number of languages, not only zsh.

Answer (score 3):

*If* the question is tagged [zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zsh), it will already apply syntax highlighting 'shell style'. You can see that by checking the [Tag Info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/zsh/info); at the bottom there's a little message:

> Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js)): lang-bsh

For the record, ♦ moderators are able to change this.

Stack Exchange highlighting isn't smart enough to parse shebangs, but we can help it by applying the correct tags to questions.

Comment: Today I learned about changing highlighting for tags -- thank you!